# CSS keep footer at bottom

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to keep my footer at the bottom of the page using CSS.
Please explain in simpler terms as I am new to HTML, CSS and BootStrap.

HTML:

```
<div id="footer-bottom">            
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="widget widget-text">
                    <div class="copyright"> 
                        <p class="last">
                            2015. AVENTIS. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
                        </p>          
                    </div>  
                </div><!-- widget-text -->
            </div><!-- col -->       
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="widget widget-social">          
                    <div class="social-media">
                        <a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="google" href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a class="pinterest" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>                                                    
                    </div><!-- social-media -->                     
                </div><!-- widget-social -->  
            </div><!-- col -->
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer-bottom {
    padding: 30px 0;
    background-color: #084C8D;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    bottom:0;
    left:0; 
}
```

the footer is currently stuck between my content and not at the bottom of the webpage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

Comment: i check your code in chrome it was working fine

Comment: Is your `#footer-bottom` div inside any other element, or it is just inside the body? Maybe that is the problem, you should place it in the body. Also, you should add some `margin-bottom` to your `body` element equal as the footer's height. Or, if you want your footer to be always visible at the bottom of the screen, you should use `position:fixed;`

Comment: @Mahadevan Hey, sorry forgot to add this. My code works fine on pages with content that fits all within one page. It doesnt work on pages that require scrolling.

Comment: Try  `clear:both;` in the css
Edit: Nevermind, did not know you wanted it fixed to the bottom while scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
}
#footer-bottom {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: #084C8D;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet
    vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper
    sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis
    quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est. Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc
    diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis, nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat,
    arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis
    pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum purus convallis
    nulla ultrices ultricies. Nullam aliquam, mi eu aliquam tincidunt, purus velit laoreet tortor, viverra pretium nisi quam vitae mi. Fusce vel volutpat elit. Nam sagittis nisi dui. Suspendisse lectus leo, consectetur in tempor sit amet, placerat quis
    neque. Etiam luctus porttitor lorem, sed suscipit est rutrum non. Curabitur lobortis nisl a enim congue semper. Aenean commodo ultrices imperdiet. Vestibulum ut justo vel sapien venenatis tincidunt. Phasellus eget dolor sit amet ipsum dapibus condimentum
    vitae quis lectus. Aliquam ut massa in turpis dapibus convallis. Praesent elit lacus, vestibulum at malesuada et, ornare et est. Ut augue nunc, sodales ut euismod non, adipiscing vitae orci. Mauris ut placerat justo. Mauris in ultricies enim. Quisque
    nec est eleifend nulla ultrices egestas quis ut quam. Donec sollicitudin lectus a mauris pulvinar id aliquam urna cursus. Cras quis ligula sem, vel elementum mi. Phasellus non ullamcorper urna. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia
    nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In euismod ultrices facilisis. Vestibulum porta sapien adipiscing augue congue id pretium lectus molestie. Proin quis dictum nisl. Morbi id quam sapien, sed vestibulum sem. Duis elementum rutrum mauris sed convallis.
    Proin vestibulum magna mi. Aenean tristique hendrerit magna, ac facilisis nulla hendrerit ut. Sed non tortor sodales quam auctor elementum. Donec hendrerit nunc eget elit pharetra pulvinar. Suspendisse id tempus tortor. Aenean luctus, elit commodo
    laoreet commodo, justo nisi consequat massa, sed vulputate quam urna quis eros. Donec vel.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur
    ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet.
    Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies.
    Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est. Vivamus fermentum semper porta. Nunc diam velit, adipiscing ut tristique vitae, sagittis vel odio. Maecenas convallis ullamcorper ultricies. Curabitur ornare, ligula semper consectetur sagittis,
    nisi diam iaculis velit, id fringilla sem nunc vel mi. Nam dictum, odio nec pretium volutpat, arcu ante placerat erat, non tristique elit urna et turpis. Quisque mi metus, ornare sit amet fermentum et, tincidunt et orci. Fusce eget orci a orci congue
    vestibulum. Ut dolor diam, elementum et vestibulum eu, porttitor vel elit. Curabitur venenatis pulvinar tellus gravida ornare. Sed et erat faucibus nunc euismod ultricies ut id justo. Nullam cursus suscipit nisi, et ultrices justo sodales nec. Fusce
    venenatis facilisis lectus ac semper. Aliquam at massa ipsum. Quisque bibendum purus convallis nulla ultrices ultricies. Nullam aliquam, mi eu aliquam tincidunt, purus velit laoreet tortor, viverra pretium nisi quam vitae mi. Fusce vel volutpat elit.
    Nam sagittis nisi dui. Suspendisse lectus leo, consectetur in tempor sit amet, placerat quis neque. Etiam luctus porttitor lorem, sed suscipit est rutrum non. Curabitur lobortis nisl a enim congue semper. Aenean commodo ultrices imperdiet. Vestibulum
    ut justo vel sapien venenatis tincidunt. Phasellus eget dolor sit amet ipsum dapibus condimentum vitae quis lectus. Aliquam ut massa in turpis dapibus convallis. Praesent elit lacus, vestibulum at malesuada et, ornare et est. Ut augue nunc, sodales
    ut euismod non, adipiscing vitae orci. Mauris ut placerat justo. Mauris in ultricies enim. Quisque nec est eleifend nulla ultrices egestas quis ut quam. Donec sollicitudin lectus a mauris pulvinar id aliquam urna cursus. Cras quis ligula sem, vel
    elementum mi. Phasellus non ullamcorper urna. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In euismod ultrices facilisis. Vestibulum porta sapien adipiscing augue congue id pretium lectus molestie. Proin
    quis dictum nisl. Morbi id quam sapien, sed vestibulum sem. Duis elementum rutrum mauris sed convallis. Proin vestibulum magna mi. Aenean tristique hendrerit magna, ac facilisis nulla hendrerit ut. Sed non tortor sodales quam auctor elementum. Donec
    hendrerit nunc eget elit pharetra pulvinar. Suspendisse id tempus tortor. Aenean luctus, elit commodo laoreet commodo, justo nisi consequat massa, sed vulputate quam urna quis eros. Donec vel.</p>
  <div id="footer-bottom">

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">

          <div class="widget widget-text">

            <div class="copyright">
              <p class="last">
                2015. AVENTIS. ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
              </p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!-- widget-text -->

        </div>
        <!-- col -->

        <div class="col-sm-6">

          <div class="widget widget-social">

            <div class="social-media">

              <a class="facebook" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
              <a class="twitter" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              <a class="google" href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
              <a class="pinterest" href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a> 

            </div>
            <!-- social-media -->

          </div>
          <!-- widget-social -->

        </div>
        <!-- col -->
      </div>
      <!-- row -->
    </div>
    <!-- container -->

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

In your css, change Position: absolute; to Position: Fixed;

Comment: Hi, I have tried changing it to Position:Fixed; before and it did set my footer to the bottom. However, the footer scrolls along with my webpage. Is there a way to permanently fix the footer at the bottom, where the footer is only viewable once you scrolled all the way down? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't need position: absolute then, you should use position: relative;

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! The footer is now at the bottom, however there is still some white space between the footer and the exact end of the webpage. Note: the footer is stuck at the bottom and does not scroll along, but is not exactly at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @JunJie Try adding `html, body {margin: 0;}` to your CSS and see if that fixes the space you are talking about.

Comment: Is the footer always showing? and add margin: 0; to your css.

Comment: @Diamond Yes, the footer is viewable once I scroll all the way down. There is still white space though, adding margin: 0; doesnt help. http://imgur.com/5ByOgu5 Hope this helps in showing my problem better. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi, I noticed that the zoomed footer image has a white strip on top and bottom.

Is the behaviour of zooming in and out normal?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Hi, I added the codes you gave into my #page-wrapper under my CSS file. Is that correct? Adding another margin: 0; line there? Because its not working for me.. Sorry if this is basic as I'm unfamiliar with CSS codes.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that's imgur, thought it's your site *Face_Hides*

Comment: Is '<div id="footer-bottom">' sitting inside another <div> or directly in the <body> tag?

Comment: @Diamond Hi Diamond, not sure if i'm getting you right but yes there is a white strip above and below the footer, which i want to remove. And zooming in and out of the page doesn't solve the problem, the white spaces still remain. The white space does not appear on pages that does not require scrolling though. Here's an example. http://imgur.com/45fXVgJ P.S the black space is my windows task bar, which shows the footer is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Diamond it's under a <div id ="page-wrapper"> which is directly under the <body> tag. 
`html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }`

 this is the code for #page-wrapper by the way, if it helps.

Comment: set 

.page-wrapper {
margin: 0;
Padding: 0;
}

as well, to see if that will solve the problem.

Comment: @Diamond Yes Diamond, there is margin: 0; and Padding: 0 ; in #page-wrapper already.

Comment: Unless I see most of your code, I will not know where the problem is. Try inspect element in chrome and trace your output html and css

Comment: @Diamond Hey diamond, I solved it by adding another class to my CSS. So currently there are 2 footer classes in my CSS file for pages that can be scrolled and pages that doesn't require scrolling. This helps to keep the footer to the bottom of the page although it requires two different classes in the CSS file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, you might want to mark this as answer, enjoy coding!